# как вывести API на сайт

Tags: javascript, html

как и возможно ли вывести какую-то API не в консоль а прямо в браузер чтобы оно было видно сразу и
мне не приходилось заходить в консоль
например

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого достаточно полученный текст вывести в конкретный элемент на странице

Например `body`.

Так как выводить можно только строку, то нет смысла парсить полученный текст в объект, поэтому метод `.json` можно заменить методом `.text`

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => document.body.innerHTML = text);
```